# What is the meaning of the kidneys when written in paleo Hebrew?

Tags: psalms

Psalm 139:13 says:

> For thou hast possessed my reins thou hast covered me in my mother's womb (KJV)

The word 'reins' (כִּלְיָה) can also be translated as 'kidneys'. I was wondering what the original meaning is, when we look at this word written in paleo Hebrew, where the kaph looks like a bent palm and can represent the bending or subduing of the will, the lamed is in the form of a staff or yoke from a shepherd. These two 'pictures' combined could then mean 'tame for the yoke'. The other two letters could then be a reference to God (Yah).

Does anyone know more about this?

Comment: yud is a symbol of action (to give), it's related to deeds, work while hey is symbolized by praise or to behold, awe.

Comment: @sara I thought it was a good question.  I'm sorry it was closed.  Those who closed seem not to have much experience with other language writing systems and how their characters convey inherent meanings.  Chinese would be a good example here: A Chinese person can read a Chinese character that he or she has never seen before and, while unable to pronounce it, will know what it means because of the root meanings--and Hebrew has not only root letters, but the letters themselves have a rich history.  I've voted to reopen.  +1

Answer (score 3):

I am unaware of any "pictograph" writing associated with the Hebrew language which appears to date at least to the 15th century and well beyond.  The old Hebrew script, usually termed Paleo-Hebrew alphabet, as would have been in use before the Babylonian captivity and used to write the Psalms, was still a recognizable alphabet supposedly descended from the Phoenician.

To find real pictographs, one must trace the Phoenician alphabet back past its predecessor, the proto-sinaitic script, which some believe (with not much evidence) descended from Egyptian hieroglyphs.  Even these were highly stylized.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_hieroglyphs

Thus, the Hebrew alphabets are well-removed from their distant ancestors and contain only distant traces of their ancient pictographs.  Even the script we currently use was not the script used by the authors of the Psalms.  The spelling was also presumably different.

However the meaning of our operative word in Ps 139:13 is well-understood as attested by the respected BDB in the appendix below.  here it is used as a metaphor of the seat of human emotion in a similr to our modern use of "the heart" as the seat of love and emotion.

**APPENDIX - BDB entry for כִּלְיָה**

> [כִּלְיָה noun feminine only plural kidneys (Late Hebrew כִּלְיָה
> (plural); Aramaic כּוּלְיָא or כּוֺלְיָא (only plural), ; Ethiopic  ᵐ5
> οἱ νεφροί); — absolute plural כְּלָיוֺת Jeremiah 11:20 5t.; כְּלָֹית
> Exodus 29:13 13t.; construct כִּלְיוֺת Deuteronomy 32:14; Isaiah 34:6;
> suffix כִּלְיוֺתַי Job 16:3 2t.; כִּלְֹיתַי Job 19:27; כִּלְיוֺתָ֑י
> Psalm 16:7; Proverbs 23:16; כִּלְֹיתָ֑י Psalm 139:13; Lamentations
> 3:13; כִּלְיוֺתֵיהֶם Jeremiah 12:2; — kidneys:
>
> **1 literally, as physical organ**,
>
> a. **of man**, only in poetry, as created by ׳י Psalm 139:13; as the
> most sensitive and vital part, in metaphor of one wounded by ׳יs
> arrows Job 16:13; Lamentations 3:13.
>
> b. **of sacrificial animals**, offered as choice part to ׳י Leviticus
> 3:4,10,15; Leviticus 4:9; Leviticus 7:4; Leviticus 9:10,19; שְׁתֵּי
> ׳הַכּ Exodus 29:13,22; Leviticus 3:4,10,15; Leviticus 4:9; Leviticus
> 7:4; Leviticus 8:16,25 (all P); in figure of sacrifice Edomites חֵלֶב
> כִּלְיוֺת אֵילִים Isaiah 34:6; transferred to wheat,חֵלֶב כִּלְיוֺת
> חִטָּה Deuteronomy 32:14 kidney-fat (i.e. the choicest, richest) of
> wheat.
>
> **2 figurative, as seat of emotion and affection** Job 19:27; Proverbs 23:16; Psalm 16:7; Psalm 73:21; קָרוֺב אַתָּה בְּפִיהֶם ׳וְרָחוֺק מִכּ
> Jeremiah 12:2 near art thou in their mouth, and far from their
> affections; hence, as involving character, the object of God's
> examination, always "" וָלֵב ׃לֵב ׳כֹּחֵן כ Jeremiah 11:20 compare
> Psalm 7:10, ׳חֹקֵר לֵב כֹּחֵן כ Jeremiah 17:10, וָלֵב ׳בֹּחֵן צַדִּיק
> רֹאֶה כ Jeremiah 20:12, וְלִבִּי ׳צָרְו֯פָה כ Psalm 26:2.

Comment: That's what I meant, paleo Hebrew, I made an edit in my post. Thanks.

Comment: @Dottard Why do you answer questions and then vote to close them so that no one else can answer it?  For one who has been awarded the local badge here in "Sportsmanship," this seems incongruous.  What makes you think you should be able to answer, but no one else qualifies?

Comment: @Polyhat - that is NOT why I answer - I try to be helpful for an enquirer but understand that the question should be closed.  My answer was supposed to show why it was not a real Bible question - word meanings in Hebrew have almost nothing to do with letter shapes and their original pictograms.  Thus, my answer was an extended way of explaining why the question should be closed.

Comment: @Dottard If you answer, the very fact of having done so shows that it is a question which can be answered, and perhaps should be.  Voting to close it after you answer is disingenuous.  It looks quite like you wish to have a monopoly on answering.

Comment: @Polyhat - that would only be true if I had the sole right to close a question which I do not.  I have voted to reopen some questions as well - see my comment above.

Comment: @Dottard You have written a very extensive answer for a non-answer which is supposedly to explain why the question should be closed.  That's a very poor explanation, in my opinion.  If _you_ don't know a better answer, it is probable that _someone else_ will, and all the greater reason you should NOT vote to close it after you have answered with your non-answer.  Have you considered how this behavior looks to those who observe it?  I am hardly the only person here who can view the voting record.

Answer (score 1):

The Jewish Publication Society's (JPS) Tanakh translates this verse:

```
   It was You who created my conscience [Lit. "kidneys"]; 
     You fashioned me in my mother’s womb. 
                (Psalm 139:13, JPS Tanakh)
```

The senses of the use of כִּלְיָה in the Mt (Leningrad) Tanakh in Logos Bible Software.

[image]

BDB Lexion:

> כִּלְיָה ... n.f. only pl. kidneys ... 1. lit., as physical organ,... 2. fig., **as seat of emotion and affection** Jb 19:27 Pr 23:16 ψ 16:7; 73:21;...
> --
> Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon (p. 480). Oxford: Clarendon Press.

```
5166
liver and kidneys

The liver and kidneys as vital internal organs of the body
Pr 7:23 See also Job 16:13; 20:24-25

The liver and kidneys are symbolic of human emotions and the conscience
Ps 73:21 The Hebrew words for liver and kidneys are occasionally translated as “heart”, “spirit” or “inmost being”. See also Job 19:27; Pr 23:16; Jer 12:2; La 2:11; 3:13

God examines the innermost being as symbolised by the kidneys Ps 26:2 See also Ps 7:9; Jer 11:20; 17:10; 20:12

God is concerned for the innermost being as symbolised by the kidneys Ps 139:13 See also Ps 16:7


Manser, M. H. (2009). Dictionary of Bible Themes: The Accessible and Comprehensive Tool for Topical Studies. London: Martin Manser.
```

> In the Bible “kidney” is used both literally and figuratively. When the word is used figuratively of humans, KJV usually translates the term as “reins” (Jer. 12:2; Rev. 2:23, NRSV uses “mind”), “heart” (Job 19:27; Pss. 7:9; 16:7, 73:21; Jer. 12:2), “vitals” (Lam. 3:13), “soul” (Prov. 23:16), or “inward parts” (Ps. 139:13; cp. Job 16:13).

> The kidneys are often associated with the heart as constituting the center of human personality (Pss. 7:9; 26:2; Jer. 11:20; 17:10; 20:12; Rev. 2:23). Because the areas around the kidneys are sensitive, the Hebrews believed the kidneys were the seat of the emotions (Job 19:27; Ps. 73:21; Prov. 23:16). The kidneys were also used figuratively as the source of the knowledge and understanding of the moral life (Ps. 16:7; Jer. 12:2).
> --
> Brand, C., Draper, C., England, A., Bond, S., Clendenen, E. R., & Butler, T. C. (Eds.). (2003). Kidney. In Holman Illustrated Bible Dictionary (p. 983). Nashville, TN: Holman Bible Publishers.

> **kidneys** (Heb. kelayot; Gk. nephroi), part of the group of fat pieces burned on the altar in sacrificial offerings (Exod. 29:22; Lev. 3:4; 4:9; 7:4). In the NRSV, the term “kidneys” is used only once with reference to the human organ (Job 16:13). The Hebrew and Greek terms, however, are used elsewhere, in two different contexts. First, the Hebrews sometimes used the term “kidneys” as a generic reference to one’s inner organs (cf. Ps. 139:13, NRSV: “inward parts”; Lam. 3:13, NRSV: “vitals”). Second, the ancient Hebrews seem to have thought of the kidneys as the seat of emotion or conscience (similar to the role assigned to the heart in modern Western thought). Thus, the Bible refers to God as, literally, searching the kidneys of people to know their true self (Jer. 11:20; 20:12; Ps. 73:21); likewise people may be “upright in kidneys” (Ps. 7:10), and when their speech is insincere, they may be said to have God near to their mouths but far from their kidneys (Jer. 12:2). Their kidneys may rejoice with gladness (Prov. 23:16) or faint with fear (Job 19:27). The NRSV uses “heart” or “hearts” in all of these passages, except Prov. 23:16, where it uses “soul.” See also fat; heart.
> --
> Powell, M. A. (2011). kidneys. In M. A. Powell (Ed.), The HarperCollins Bible Dictionary (Revised and Updated) (Third Edition, p. 513). New York: HarperCollins.

> When kidney refers to human beings, it is always used symbolically to mean someone’s mind (Ps. 16:7; Jer. 12:2) or innermost being (Job 17:3; Prov. 23:16). Sometimes when kidney is used this way, it is translated “heart.” A common biblical expression is that God examines the “kidneys and heart”—that He thoroughly knows a person’s inner thoughts and motives (Ps. 7:9; 26:2; Jer. 11:20; Rev. 2:23; reins and heart, KJV).
> --
> Youngblood, R. F., Bruce, F. F., & Harrison, R. K., Thomas Nelson Publishers (Eds.). (1995). In Nelson’s new illustrated Bible dictionary. Nashville, TN: Thomas Nelson, Inc.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and the fact that you did not also vote to close the question.  +1